# Using QFrame to display different panes of information?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'm trying to get a QFrame to serve as a "display area" for a couple different kinds of information, eg: you click on something in a list view and an info pane shows up in the frame 
to give you information about it, you click on a different item and a different pane shows up.

Having trouble swapping the different frames in and out of the QFrame though, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`QStackedWidget`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qstackedwidget.html) is probably the most standard solution.